# Where to find Unified Soil Classification System .Style?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, autocad, style-manager

I'm looking for the Unified Soil Classification .style patterns to add to my style manager. I haven't had much luck with a variety of web searches for either ArcMap and AutoCAD. 
Does anyone know where I might be able to find them?

Comment: What makes you think that a `*.style` for Unified Soil Classification has been created by anyone?